Vercel Template - ⨯ TypeError: "secret" is required
I recently deployed a Vercel template, and the site is up and running. However, when I want to edit the website, I clone my GitHub repository, and then want to see live website updates with localhost by running the command npm run dev.
The issue is, I get this error:
GET / 500 in 4156ms
 ⨯ TypeError: "secret" is required
    at get (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:818:15)
    at getConfig (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:3350:45)
    at SessionCache.getConfig (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:3422:44)
    at get (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:2572:39)
    at Object.getSession (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:2414:51)
    at Home (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/[root of the server]__aaec46._.js:642:149)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "810301068"
 ⨯ TypeError: "secret" is required
    at get (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:818:15)
    at getConfig (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:3350:45)
    at SessionCache.getConfig (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:3422:44)
    at get (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:2572:39)
    at Object.getSession (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/node_modules_@auth0_nextjs-auth0_dist_a3dbad._.js:2414:51)
    at Home (/Users/alexander/theta-s-a-a-s/.next/server/chunks/ssr/[root of the server]__aaec46._.js:642:149)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "810301068"

It says a secret is required, and I know this is to do with environmental variables not properly working, but I need help with how to fix this. I've found this issue online like, here, but I'm still struggling to figure out how to fix this.
Link Here
It would be much appreciated if explained in layman's terms.
